# Mochi without a Mochi mixer

Tags: rice-cooker, stand-mixer

Can a kitchen aide mixer, with a dough hook, do the same (or nearly the same) job as a Mochi Maker which costs nearly $300?

Comment: Googling "mochi mixer" led to several websites saying how to make mochi with a Kithenaid mixer. Whether the results will meet your expectations, i don't know.